# Is it dark inside a black hole?

Tags: black-hole, light

Assuming you could be standing inside a black hole, would it be light or dark around you?

Comment: Define "Inside a black hole"

Comment: "Below/inside the event horizon"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only light you would see, would be from the stars outside the black hole. Any light that is generated inside the event horizon would be refracted towards the singularity. You wouldn't see the object in front of you since the light would not reach your eye.

Comment: Say you're inside the event horizon facing outwards. If you shine a torch into your face, you would see that light wouldn't you?

Comment: Yes, you should.

Comment: in that case, you might want to revise the last sentence of your answer "You wouldn't see the object in front of you since the light would not reach your eye."

Comment: @Carl You picked a specific direction in your question. Now, you are just nick-picking since the answer depends on a specific direction instead of a general direction. If you were facing the other way, you wouldn't see any light even if the torch is directly on your eye.

Comment: just suggesting an improvement to your answer is all. The question doesn't specify a direction, yet you mention the light coming from stars outside. Might be more accurate to specify light coming from the event horizon be it inside the event horizon or outside of it.

Comment: This is incorrect: "You wouldn't see the object in front of you since the light would not reach your eye." That would violate the equivalence principle; besides, a Penrose diagram of a black hole spacetime clearly implies that this is incorrect in without some *substantial* qualification.

Answer (score 1):

As said above, you'd see the light coming into the black hole but you mught also see a dim light from Hawking radiation.